# Not able to call @Autowired Service in controller class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

**Here is my spring controller class KalamController**

```
package com.kalam.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.kalam.model.Employee;
import com.kalam.service.EmployeeService;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class KalamController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping("/kalam")
    public String showMessage(ModelMap map) {



        map.put("dollar", "50 US $");

        return "KalamWorld";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/insertData")
    public void InserData() {

        Employee emp= new Employee();
        emp.setEmpID(7);
        emp.setEmpName("Prashant");
    emp.setEmpSalary(20000);
        emp.setAddress("Vashi");


        employeeService.addEmployee(emp);
    } 

}
```

**Hibernate config xml file**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<!-- Activate Spring annotation support -->
<context:annotation-config />

<mvc:annotation-driven /> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.serviceimpl" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.daoimpl" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.testclass" />





<!-- DataSource configurationt -->
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kalamdb"></property>  
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>  
    </bean>  

   <bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

        <property name="mappingResources">  
        <list>  
        <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>  
        </list>  
        </property>  

        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  
            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>




 <bean id="employeeDaoImpl" class="com.kalam.daoimpl.EmployeeDaoImpl">    
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory" />
 </bean>  

     <bean id="employeeDaoImpl" class="com.kalam.daoimpl.EmployeeDaoImpl" /> 
    <bean id="employeeService" class="com.kalam.service.EmployeeService" /> 
     <bean id="kalamController" class="com.kalam.controller.KalamController" /> 


     <bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
              <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory" />
       </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />



    </beans>
```

**EmployeeServiceimpl. java file**

```
package com.kalam.serviceimpl;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.kalam.dao.EmployeeDao;
import com.kalam.daoimpl.EmployeeDaoImpl;
import com.kalam.model.Employee;
import com.kalam.service.EmployeeService;

@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{


    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;


    public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {

        employeeDao.addEmployee(emp);

    }

    public void updateEmployee(Employee emp) {


}


    public void deleteEmployee(Employee emp,int id) {

    }
}
```

**And finally EmployeeDaoImpl.java class**

```
package com.kalam.daoimpl;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.kalam.dao.EmployeeDao;
import com.kalam.model.Employee;

@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl  {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



    public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {


        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx= session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(emp);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public void updateEmployee(Employee emp) {

          Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(emp);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void deleteEmployee(Employee emp, int id) {

          Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          session.beginTransaction();
            Employee employee = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, new Integer(id));
            if(null != employee){
                session.delete(emp);

                                }
            session.getTransaction().commit();

    }



    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

**When i run the program i get following error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kalamController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.kalam.service.EmployeeService com.kalam.controller.KalamController.employeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kalam.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5633)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1694)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1684)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.kalam.service.EmployeeService com.kalam.controller.KalamController.employeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kalam.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kalam.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 24 more
```

**Please tell me whats going wrong. Did i forget any configuration in xml file? My intention is to know how i can call service in controller using @Autowired annotation.**

Comment: Hi Nitin, I think the place where you are defining the bean is not correct kindly follow the attached link that would guide you to define a bean in appropriate place. https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html

Comment: How are you configuring spring?  Using annotations requires that you enable classpath scanning with the correct base package (in your case `com.kalam`).  If you have an application context xml, can you post that?

Comment: Agree olambert's idea, please make sure you have confingure the scan path. or if you are using spring boot, please make  sure you have put the EmployeeDaoImpl  in the jar of "@SpringBootApplication"

Comment: Thank you srikant and olambert. i will make changes as per your suggestion and will provide feedback also. Olambert i have done component scanning in Hibernate-cfg.xml file itself. You can see the same file above where i have post the question.

Comment: Hi @olambert  i did both the changes as per your guidance. Still i'm facing same error again.

Comment: hi @srikanthr i did your suggestion. still im facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your configuration (Hibernate Config Xml) file instead of using

```
<bean id="employeeService" class="com.kalam.service.EmployeeService" />
```

you need to use

```
<bean id="employeeService" class="com.kalam.serviceimpl.EmployeeServiceImpl"/>
```

You are passing **EmployeeService** to the bean Which is **Interface**.
Pass the Implemented class and take the reference and use in Controller as

```
 @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.serviceimpl" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.daoimpl" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.testclass" />
```

Try to use

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.controller, com.kalam.serviceimpl ..." />
```

Comment: Thank you stanislavL. I will make your suggested changes.